# Adding custom product attribute to transactional emails in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, email, magento, transactional, magento-1.9.1

I need to print two text attributes below the item ordered in a magento new order template. I've searched and found multiple ways, but they do not seem to work for 1.9 as far as I tried. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, but it never seems to be explained clearly.

Sample code as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td class="order-details">
        <h3>Your order <span class="no-link">#{{var order.increment_id}}</span></h3>
        <p>Placed on {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="order-information">
//preferably custom product attribute prints here
    <td>
        {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
            <tr>
                <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
            </tr>
```

I'm new to magento, but I'd like to get this right. Could anyone please point me in the right direction to get the two custom product attributes to print in the 1.9 email template?

Comment: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/25/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates/ this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
//$order =order object
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){    
      $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
      echo  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but where would I put this? in the transaction email template in the magento editor or somewhere in the backend?

Comment: As noted by the OP question: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.